# Adding the value from select option of a form to firebase

Tags: firebase

I can not seem to add values from my form's select option field into firebase. I keep getting this error from the console:

> Error: Key X was undefined. Cannot pass undefined in JSON. Use null instead.

Anybody with a solution at all. thank you so much in advance.

Comment: a bit of your code (select & the controller you pass the data in) might help figuring out why you get the error

Comment: Hi D (Dr.?) Steve. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).